# how to output xml with attribute and field value in TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I'd like to output some fields from a table in xml. I need to put the name of the column in the name-attribute. The output must resemble:

```
<udfields>
<udfield name="infoplanner">Test for the info</udfield>
<udfield name="plant">Amsterdam</udfield>
<udfield name="capability"/>
</udfields>
```

I tried things like:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    ko.infoPlanner AS "udfield/name/@infoplanner"
  , ko.plant AS "udfield/name/@plant"
  , ko.capability AS "udfield/name/@capability"
FROM    sometable ko
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ko.datumtijd, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
        AND COALESCE(ko.infoPlanner, '') <> ''
FOR     XML PATH('')
```

thanks in advance, leon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
declare @T table
(
  infoplanner int,
  plant int,
  capability int
)

insert into @T
select 1, 2, 3 union all
select 10, 20 ,30

select (select 'infoplanner' as '@name', 
               infoplanner as '*' 
        for xml path('udfield'), type),
       (select 'plant' as '@name',
               plant as '*' 
        for xml path('udfield'), type),
       (select 'capability' as '@name',
               capability as '*' 
        for xml path('udfield'), type)
from @T
for xml path('udfields')
```

Result:

```
<udfields>
  <udfield name="infoplanner">1</udfield>
  <udfield name="plant">2</udfield>
  <udfield name="capability">3</udfield>
</udfields>
<udfields>
  <udfield name="infoplanner">10</udfield>
  <udfield name="plant">20</udfield>
  <udfield name="capability">30</udfield>
</udfields>
```

Comment: @lcarpay good to hear. If it is what you want you should accept the answer using the check mark on the left side.